# How to force Maven to use jcenter repoistory

Tags: maven, jcenter

I was trying to get dependencies with mvn, but the problem is that one of packages is not in the officail repo. I've mananged to add jcenter to the sources, but maven seems not olwes to take look there.

Here it is looking correctly to the next repo

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/ktor/ktor-client-core/1.2.5/ktor-client-core-1.2.5.pom
Downloading from central: https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/ktor/ktor-client-core/1.2.5/ktor-client-core-1.2.5.pom
```

but here dont:

```
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/io/ktor/ktor-http/1.2.5/ktor-http-1.2.5.pom
[WARNING] Missing POM for io.ktor:ktor-http:jar:1.2.5
```

`mvn -Dartifact=io.ktor:ktor-client-core:1.2.5 -DremoteRepositories=central::default::https://jcenter.bintray.com/  dependency:get`

Comment: While I see you decided to switch from Maven to Gradle, if you were to remain with Gradle then to use the JCenter repository you'd just need `repositories { jcenter() }` in the build file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `io.ktor` artifacts are currently not available at Maven Central for versions newer than 1.2.4. Therefore they have to be downloaded from the [Jcenter repository](https://jcenter.bintray.com).

`ktor-http` has a depencency `ktor-utils`. When calling the dependency plugin for `ktor-http` Maven tries to download also the `ktor-utils` artifact. Unfortunately, the parameter `-DremoteRepositories=` is only taken into account for the artifact `ktor-http` but not for the dependency `ktor-utils`. Maven tries to download `ktor-utils` from Maven central and fails.

You could solve the problem by calling

```
mvn -Dartifact=io.ktor:ktor-utils:1.2.5 -DremoteRepositories=central::default::https://jcenter.bintray.com/  dependency:get
```

before downloading `ktor-http`. However, this approach requires a lot of manual download steps and I would not suggest it.

A better solution would be to [add](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html) the Jcenter repository directly to your pom:

```
<project>
  [...]
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>jcenter</id>
      <name>jcenter</name>
      <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  [...]
</project>
```

A third option would be to add the Jcenter repository to your `settings.xml`.

Comment: You coud create a pom, just for the download of the artifacts. Or you download the artifacts manually as I have described in the first part of the answer.

Comment: generally i've dropped mvn dependency and using direct download https://github.com/majkrzak/kot/blob/master/src/resolver.py

Comment: I was just going to add that you could add the additional repo to your settings.xml, but looking at your link this won't help you..

Comment: you can add it to the answswer anyway